# Why dynamically created Radmenu ItemClick event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radmenu

I am dynamically creating a RadMenu. I want to use the menu click event of the RadMenu.

Actually I am using `if(!Scriptmanager.IsInAsyncPostBack)` condition.

Within the `if` condition I only write code to create the menu dynamically. I'll give the sample code for better understanding.

```
if (!src.IsInAsyncPostBack)
{                  
    RadMenu menu = new RadMenu();
    RadMenuItem item1 = new RadMenuItem();
    item1.Text = "Home";
    RadMenuItem item11 = new RadMenuItem();
    item11.Text = "Home";
    item1.Items.Add(item11);                 
    RadMenuItem item2 = new RadMenuItem();
    item2.Text = "About";
    RadMenuItem item3 = new RadMenuItem();
    item3.Text = "Contact";
    menu.ItemClick += new RadMenuEventHandler(menu_ItemClick);                  

    menu.Items.Add(item1);
    menu.Items.Add(item2);
    menu.Items.Add(item3);
    Page.Controls.Add(menu);
}

void menu_ItemClick(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```

When page loading `if(!IsInAsyncPostBack)` condition true so the RadMenu is created dynamically and loaded in the page.

When I click the menu item, Postback becomes true, so the if condition fails and the menu
click event is not firing.

I wrote the menu click event outside of the if condition. In this case the menu click event is also not firing.

My exact requirement is that I want to use `if(!IsInAsyncPostBack)` postback condition as well as I need to use menu click event. Is it possible?

Comment: Where you have written this code? (Means inside page_init, page_load and inside any condition)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the Page_Init event and remove the if (!src.IsInAsyncPostBack) check. THis is the easiest way to create controls programmatically.

Probably your menu is ajax-enabled so a POST from it is partial, so your code does not recreate it, so it cannot raise its handler.